# TeamCity: Can't choose my uploaded SSH key when configuring the VCS root

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, teamcity, ssh-keys

Trying to integrate a new TeamCity project with an existing git-bitbucket repo.

I am a rather limited user on our TeamCity platform (on-prem, 2017.1.3-46961). I do not have access to the actual server file system, I am using the web interface, instead.

Created an SSH key pair on my laptop with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`

In our TeamCity, I uploaded the SSH key (private side):
[image]

However, when trying to set up my VCS root with that key, I cannot see it in the drop-down:
[image]

This VCS Root is in the project where the SSH key has been uploaded.
Should have I uploaded the key somewhere else?

Or, maybe, this is a TeamCity bug?
I tried basic shake-up like hard-refreshing the page, logging out/in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the VCS root was created in the specific project, it somehow `belongs to <root project>`. Once I added the SSH key in the root project, it was available for selection in the dropdown above and connection test to bitbucket has passed.